# Fabric.js - Is it possible to draw objects on top of already present objects?

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

I'm currently working on an application that will allow lines and shapes to be drawn on top of imported images inside of a fabric.js canvas. As of right now I've only been able to do this in Fabric by assigning the image to be the canvas background. When I attempt to load the image and place it within the canvas, via

```
fabric.Image.fromURL()
```

I'm not able to draw shapes or lines while hovering over the image. I'm only able to do so if the cursor is placed outside the confines of the image. Is there anyway to get around this using the fabric.Image.fromURL() method to load an image and allow shapes/lines to be drawn on-top of it?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure [object.evented](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Object.html#evented)  is set to false on the image you want to be able to draw on.

When set to `false`, an object can not be a target of events. All events propagate through it.